# Object in the HashMap are overwritten - java

Tags: java, mysql, hashmap, overwrite

I would like to create an HashMap where the key is a string and the value is a List. All the values are taken from a Mysql table. The problem is that I have an HashMap where the key is the right one while the value is not the right one, because it is overwritten. In fact I have for all different keys the same list with the same content.
This is the code:

```
public static HashMap<String,List<Table_token>> getHashMapFromTokenTable() throws SQLException, Exception{

DbAccess.initConnection();
List<Table_token> listFrom_token = new ArrayList();
HashMap<String,List<Table_token>> hMapIdPath = new HashMap<String,List<Table_token>>();

String query = "select * from token";
resultSet = getResultSetByQuery(query);

while(resultSet.next()){

    String token=resultSet.getString(3);
    String path=resultSet.getString(4);
    String word=resultSet.getString(5);
    String lemma=resultSet.getString(6);
    String postag=resultSet.getString(7);
    String isTerminal=resultSet.getString(8);
    Table_token t_token = new Table_token();
    t_token.setIdToken(token);
    t_token.setIdPath(path);
    t_token.setWord(word);
    t_token.setLemma(lemma);
    t_token.setPosTag(postag);
    t_token.setIsTerminal(isTerminal);
    listFrom_token.add(t_token);
    System.out.println("path "+path+" path2: "+token);
    int row = resultSet.getRow();

    if(resultSet.next()){
        if((resultSet.getString(4).compareTo(path)!=0)){    
            hMapIdPath.put(path, listFrom_token);
                listFrom_token.clear();
            }
        resultSet.absolute(row);

    }
    if(resultSet.isLast()){
        hMapIdPath.put(path, listFrom_token);
            listFrom_token.clear();
    }

}

DbAccess.closeConnection();

return hMapIdPath;

}
```

You can find an example of the content of the HashMap below:

key: p000000383
content: [t0000000000000019231, t0000000000000019232, t0000000000000019233]

key: p000000384
content: [t0000000000000019231, t0000000000000019232, t0000000000000019233]

The values that are in "content" are in the last rows in Mysql table for the same key.

```
    mysql> select * from token where idpath='p000003361';
+---------+------------+----------------------+------------+
| idDoc   | idSentence | idToken              | idPath     |
+---------+------------+----------------------+------------+
| d000095 | s000000048 | t0000000000000019231 | p000003361 |
| d000095 | s000000048 | t0000000000000019232 | p000003361 |
| d000095 | s000000048 | t0000000000000019233 | p000003361 |
+---------+------------+----------------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: Do you really mean to call resultSet.next() in the middle of your loop through the resultSet, or do you mean hasNext()?

Comment: You should be able to debug through this and see at which point it's writing to the hashmap with a key that already exists in the hashmap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allocate a new `listFrom_token` each time instead of `clear()`ing it.  Replace this:

```
            listFrom_token.clear();
```

with:

```
            listFrom_token = new ArrayList<Table_token>();
```

Putting the list in the `HashMap` does *not* make a copy of the list.  You are clearing and refilling the same list over and over.

Comment: @Ema: by the way, your control flow is overly complicated.  After you build your `t_token`, you should just do `if (!hMapIdPath.containsKey(path)) { hMapIdPath.put(path, new ArrayList<Table_token>()); } hMapIdPath.get(path).add(t_token);`

Comment: ah ok...I will try, It's the first time I am using HaspMap! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your data shows that idPath is not a primary key.  That's what you need to be the key in the Map.  Maybe you should make idToken the key in the Map - it's the only thing in your example that's unique.

Your other choice is to make the column name the key and give the values to the List.  Then you'll have four keys, each with a List containing four values.

Comment: The primary key is idToken. For each idpath there are one or more idPath, so that's why I want to use an HashMap where the key is the path, and the value is a list that contains all idTokens for the current path.